# Can we use same OData Webservice instance to serve content from different Brokers

Tags: broker, odata

If we have 3 web-applications pointing to 3 different Brokers then how the OData-webservice instance should be configured to serve the content for all 3 web-applications. Do we need to setup 3 Odata-webservice instance or the same can be used; please share comments on same; Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In short: no.

You can only bind one database to each service. May I ask why you're using 3 different brokers?